# ruby return split string into 3 parts

Tags: ruby

I need to write methods in ruby that retrieves the first 3 characters of a string, the next 3 and finally the remaining 4 characters of a string.
So for example if a number "2134588967" is stored as a string, then i need methods that return:

"213"

"458"

"8967"

If the string is less than 8 characters the method shouldn't throw an error. Maybe just return nil.

Is there a way to do this without any regex expression?

Comment: Note that @Linuxious could have instead written `[s[0,3],s[3,3],s[6,4]]`.  You may be relieved to know that if you decide to change your SO name in future, you can do so without losing your reputation points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
def method(str)
  str.length < 8 ? nil : [str[0..2], str[3..5], str[6..10]]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty approach

```
split_number("12345678")

def split_number(string)
  return nil if string.length < 8
  puts string[0..2]
  puts string[3..5]
  puts string[6..9]
end
```